# Store and compare with previous result where do I place counter

Tags: javascript, counter

Hello I need to compare a previous result that I'm getting from an API with the new one. The thing is that I don't know the value that I'll be getting. Therefore, I use a random function and a variable called oldShowNumber that will store the old result from the API and compare it to the new one which I'll call newrandom.

I tried to use a counter so the next time it enters inside the counter > 1 condition. Am I overcomplicating myself?

This is my script:

```js
var array= ["100", "200", "300", "300"]
var newrandom = array[Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length)];

let counter= 1

var oldShowNumber= "";


(function (param){
  if(counter <= 1){
    oldShowNumber += param
    
    counter +=1
    
  } else if( counter > 1){
    if(oldShowNumber === param){
      console.log("They are the same it should stop")
    }
  }

})(newrandom)



console.log(oldShowNumber)
```

Comment: Remember the `+` operator is overloaded to include string concatenation. So `"20"+20==="2020"` and`20+20 === 40`

Answer (score 1):

You need to store the information whether you already have an old number and if yes, the value of said number.

A common technique is to initialize a variable with to `undefined` to refer to the first case and assign a number in the second case.

Therefore: Initialize `oldShowNumber` with `undefined` and replace

```
var oldShowNumber= "";
....
if (counter <= 1) {
...
} else if (counter > 1) {
...
}
```

with

```
var oldShowNumber; // identical with: var oldShowNumber = undefined;
....
if (oldShowNumber === undefined) {
...
} else {
...
}
```